# Issues with matrix division

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have this matrix division issue. I have something like this

```
(AxB)/(C*C).
```

I think I can write it as

```
(A/C) * (B/C). Correct me if I am wrong.
```

Now is there any way to eliminate this from taking this form. B and C are both very huge matrices and calculating B/C takes almost 1 minute in matlab. So is there any other way I can manipulate this?

Comment: Unless there's something special about the matrices, in general they don't commute.  You can't migrate one of the C past the B like that.

Answer (score 4):

If all of your matrices are square, then for your first expression you have the equivalence

```
A * B / (C * C) <==> A * B * inv(C * C) <==> A * B * inv(C) * inv(C)
```

On the other hand, your second expression is equivalent to

```
(A / C) * (B / C) <==> A * inv(C) * B * inv(C)
```

Since matrices don't commute in general, these don't have to be the same. If we equate the right-hand sides, we find that (as long as `A` and `C` are invertible) we can make some cancellations, and end up with the equation

```
B * inv(C) == inv(C) * B
```

i.e. the two expressions are the same if `B` commutes with `inv(C)`. In fact we can multiply on the left and right by `C`, and get

```
C * B = B * C
```

so this is the same as requiring that `B` commutes with `C`.